# Gnuplot - Fixing see-through 3D plot interpolation

Tags: gnuplot

In the picture below, you can see the lines through the interpolated surface. How can I prevent this from happening? I have produced the plot by the following commands ("data.txt" holds a set of points that represent the surface sin(x^2+y^2)/(x^2+y^2):

```
set pm3d interpolate 0,0
set dgrid3d 30,30
splot "data.txt" with lines
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no Gnuplot expert, but by looking at the [documentation](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.0/gnuplot.pdf) page 161 shows the `set style fill` command.

From the documentation it says:

> The default fillstyle is **empty**.
>   The **solid** option causes filling with a solid color, if the terminal supports that. The  parameter
>   specifies the intensity of the fill color. At a  of 0.0, the box is empty, at  of 1.0, the inner
>   area is of the same color as the current linetype. Some terminal types can vary the density continuously;
>   others implement only a few levels of partial fill. If no  parameter is given, it defaults to 1.

In your case, I believe you want to the command that is along the line of `set style fill transparent 1` or `set style fill solid 1`. You'd have to see how they both look and choose the one that is best. You could also mess with the alpha value and try something like 0.85 to see if it looks better than a completely solid fill.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways you can try, and check if they suit your needs

```
set pm3d depthorder
```

or

```
set hidden3d ...
```

More elaborate examples: [gnuplot demo script: hidden2.dem](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/hidden2.html)